# Address generating an error with the maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have been using the google maps API for quite some time with no problems until today. I have a single address that is not mapping with the API, but if I go to maps.google.com, the address is found and displayed.

Reference to the google maps API is obtained via:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

My code follows below and the values input are:

**From** is my address

**end** address is: 3601 Wetumpka Hwy, Montgomery, AL 36110

**waypoints** is [].

The error occurs in the **I.getSouthWest** function as 'c is undefined' (as reported in Firefox using Firebug).

As I said, this has worked fine for months and it is only this single address causes a problem. Any ideas? Do you need any further information? Wat could be causing the problem?

```
    var request = {
        origin: from,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    // this line generates error
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        if(save==0){
            customPanel(map,"map_canvas",route,document.getElementById("path"));
            drawCircles(route, map);
            showRates(branch,endZip,ctr++,document.getElementById('ttlDistance').value,0,0,doProcess);
        }
        else{
           // var id_ele = document.getElementById('routeID').value;
            showRates(branch,endZip,ctr++,document.getElementById('ttlDistance').value,1,id,doProcess);
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the same location for origin (From) you would be better using the coordinates rather than the address.

```
var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(32.444526, -86.214974)//Your address
```

*origin (required) specifies the start location from which to calculate directions. This value may either be specified as a String (e.g. "Chicago, IL") or as a LatLng value*. From [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the start address is not the issue. For some reason it is the end address that is the problem. As I said, this has been working for quite a long time, but the end address shown is causing issues.